# Java Swing; How do I make it so the program starts on the right most hand of the screen?

Tags: java, swing

By default, my Swing program starts at the top left hand side of the monitor.  Is there a way to make it so it pops up at the right hand side?

What about dual monitors? Can I get it to pop on the right monitor?

Thanks.

Carlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to cover up the taskbar, you should use getMaximumWindowBounds.

[Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getMaximumWindowBounds%28%29)

http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-jframe-class-example

> Centering JFrame’s
>
> By default, a Jframe is displayed in
>   the upper-left corner of the screen.
>   To display a frame at a specified
>   location, you can use the
>   setLocation(x, y) method in the JFrame
>   class. This method places the
>   upper-left corner of a frame at
>   location (x, y).

Your pseudo code for the top right corner looks something like this:

```
yourJFrame.setLocation(
  GraphicsEnvironment.getMaximumWindowBounds().getWidth() - 
  yourJFrame.getWidth(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! This got me started--- the answer by Geoffrey Zheng solved my second problem.

Answer (score 6):

There are many questions/answers about using [`GraphicsEnvironment`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) to do similar things.

You can use `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()` to get all the monitors, then call `GraphicsDevice#getConfigurations` and then `GraphicsConfiguration#getBounds` to get the size and location of each monitor, then use your high-school geometry to find the "right" monitor. (Note that a true multi-monitor setup can put them in arbitrary location.)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the first device under GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices() will return the first most monitor? I ask because using 'high-school geometry' is possible, but not efficient if implementing in multi monitor platforms where monitors vary from 1 through 10.

Comment: "First most" monitor is ill-defined because as I said you can position multiple monitors any way you want, for example 4 monitors at the 4 vertexes of a diamond--is the top one "first most" or the left one? You can use `GraphicsEnvironment#getDefaultScreenDevice` to get the, you know, *default* monitor, but you can set any monitor to be default (at least in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

For displaying at another initial location, take a look at [`JFrame.setLocation()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28java.awt.Point%29)

For displaying on another screen, take a look at avaible infos from [`GraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getScreenDevices%28%29).